# git conflict notation showing when tried to push the commited change into master folder

Tags: git, gitlab

in our organization we maintains two folders in system one for the suer and one for the master.
both the folder are connected remotely to master and user branch respectively.
in user folder we make the changes then after add and commit and then ppush the repository to user branch in the remote.then i copied the changes to master folder  and tried to push it to master branch.

```
 Pushing to git@gitlab.emvigotech.com:root/ibox.git
To git@gitlab.emvigotech.com:root/ibox.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/BigMeanCat/CMDA'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

then then i tried

```
 pull origin master
```

then conflict arise.

help me guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for the error is you should pull the latest changes in master branch before you push into it.

the simple solution is take the back up of the changes done in the user folder .then delete the master folder in your local system.then clone the project into the master folder then pull the master branch.then copy the changes into the master folder then add,commit and push.

i think this will work for your problem.please note when ever you tried to push the new changes into master branch make sure that you pulled the last changes.

Comment: is there any simple way.